# Bash script for looping through files

Tags: bash

I have the following bash loop.

```
for file in /home/directory/*; do
filename=${file##*/}
echo "$filename"
##execute command here with $filename
done
```

How can I select only certain files? For example, only selecting files without "mask" in their filename, e.g. test-file.zip. Additionally in each loop iteration I want do declare a variable with a "mask" added, i.e. test-file-mask.zip. How can I do this?

Edit:

I think I have to be more precise. ;) So I have a folder with lots of files, for example

```
test_001.nii.gz
test_001-mask.nii.gz
test_002.nii.gz
test_002-mask.nii.gz
....
```

That means for each file, there is also a "mask" file. Now I want in each loop iteration to select both the file without mask and the file with mask. For example in the first loop iteration $file should point to test_001.nii.gz and $mask should point to test_001-mask.nii.gz and in the second loop iteration $file should point to test_002.nii.gz and $mask to test_002-mask.nii.gz etc.

Comment: I'm confused which one of the mentioned things this question is actually about. What do you mean by "declare a variable"? Would the file "masked-gentleman.zip" be selected by your criteria?

Comment: I have edited the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `find` and `sed`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
find /home/directory/* -type f -name '*.gz' \
-not -name '*mask*' | while IFS= read -r file; do

    mask="$(sed 's/^\([^.]*\)/\1-mask/' <<<"$file")"

done
```

Consider any directory name does not contain the string `mask`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have an additional problem. I want a variable $brain which should be equal to $file but the directory should be different. E.g. when $file is /home/directory/test.nii.gz then $brain should be /home/new_directory/test.nii.gz How can this be achieved?

Comment: @Thomas: Use `brain="$(sed 's:^\(/[^/]\+/\)\([^\]\+\):\1new_\2:'<<<"$file")"`

Answer (score 3):

In `[[ ... ]]`, the right hand side of a `==` can be a pattern:

```
for file in /home/directory/* ; do
    if [[ $file != *-mask.nii.gz ]] ; then
        filename=${file##*/}
        mask=${filename%.nii.gz}-mask.nii.gz
        echo "$filename" "$mask"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Note that in `bash-4.3.tar.gz`, `$extension` above would be `3.tar.gz`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Yes. But if the desired extension is `tar.gz`, the problem is very hard :-)

Comment: @choroba I have update the description, see above

Comment: @Thomas: I've updated the answer.